# Pushing objects onto an array without repeating the same

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've an array like this

```
var myArray = [{A:[{10:'a'},{11:'b'},{12:'c'}]},{B:[{10:'d'},{11:'e'},{12:'f'}]}]
```

So if I push the follwing object to the array by

```
myArray.push({A:[{10:'k'},{11:'j'},{12:'m'}]});
```

This should removes the existing array element "A" since the new one also the main is A and it should replaced by the new element.

So the new object should be like this

```
var myArray=[{A:[{10:'k'},{11:'j'},{12:'m'}]},{B:[{10:'d'},{11:'e'},{12:'f'}]}]
```

That means when the push that first element **A** get replaced by new

**EDIT**

Also A, B are dynamic. There may be more get inserted like D, E with the same sub structure for them. Actually thats the reason I used array. Its actually happening in a table with multiple pages. So if same element comes again in another page, that should replace the previous one. Thats the purpose

Comment: push will add a new value to the array, not replace a existing value.

Comment: Why do you think it should remove the existing array? `push` just adds new element to the array. BTW, why don't you use simple object instead of array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a javascript Object, they basically act like an HashMap and will replace an element if they have the same key:

```
var myJSON = {
    A: [{10:'a'},{11:'b'},{12:'c'}],
    B: [{10:'d'},{11:'e'},{12:'f'}]
};
// will change the existing 'A' object    
myJSON['A'] = [{10:'k'},{11:'j'},{12:'m'}];

// add a new element like this
myJSON['C'] = [{10: 't'}, {11: 'g'}, {12: 'm'}];
```

Comment: Corrected, also @sforsandeep it works for objects that don't exist as well.

Comment: ok, but this does not match the requirements. it changes the data structure an so the solution of the problem. but anyway. and for the records, `myJSON` is not (a) JSON. it is an object.

Comment: @NinaScholz, the actual requirements were to keep objects memorized without having repeated elements, the OP didn't ask originally for an array (though the edited question does). Also, the name `myJSON` is simply a remnant from the unedited question, that was the name OP gave to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Push on arrays will only add a new value. It's better to upgrade your entire array to an object. Now you can select the correct key and overwrite its value.

Change to :

```
var myArray = {A : [{10:'a'},{11:'b'},{12:'c'}],B : [{10:'d'},{11:'e'},{12:'f'}]};
```

Now when you do :

```
 myJSON['A'] = [{10:'k'},{11:'j'},{12:'m'}];
```

It will replace `A` with the new values.

Even when `A` doesn't exists it will be created by this construction.

You can even iterate over them by using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var myArray = {A : [{10:'a'},{11:'b'},{12:'c'}],B : [{10:'d'},{11:'e'},{12:'f'}]};
var keys = Object.keys(myArray);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
{
  document.body.innerHTML += keys[i] + " : " + myArray[keys[i]].join(", ") + "<br />";  
}
```

Comment: But the A, B are dynamic.. There may be more will come like C or D. I will mention that in the question

Comment: That doesn't matter with this construction.

Answer (score 1):

1. find index
2. if found replace the element with new data
3. if not found push the new data to the end of the array

```js
var myArray = [{ A: [{ 10: 'a' }, { 11: 'b' }, { 12: 'c' }] }, { B: [{ 10: 'd' }, { 11: 'e' }, { 12: 'f' }] }],
    newData = { A: [{ 10: 'k' }, { 11: 'j' }, { 12: 'm' }] };

function update(a, u) {
    var index;
    if (a.some(function (el, i) { return Object.keys(u)[0] in el ? (index = i, true) : false; })) {
        a[index] = u;
    } else {
        a.push(u);
    }
}
update(myArray, newData);
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myArray, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: If the OP doesn't want to change the data structure then this is the best answer!

Comment: i thought, the data structure should remain. but another question arised: is it possible, that the new data contains more than one key?